# Computing maximum and minimum value of data type using bitwise operators

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm starting to learn about the bitwise operators in Java, however, I don't quite catch the questions of computing maximum/minimum value of data types (short, byte, long , float) by using bitwise operators.

How do we start with that ? As I only found problems regarding about finding even/odd number, compute value between pairs.

Any suggestion will really help as I have spend tremendous hours just by understanding it but I haven't got anywhere so far.
Not many topics about Bitwise Operators Manipulation sadly.

Comment: Why would you need to compute the maximum value of a data type? It's a known constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the largest value, fill all the bits to 1.  The smallest value is the negation of the largest value.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<31; i++) {
           value |= 1<<i;
        }
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(~value);
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    }
}
```

Output

```
2147483647
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

See [https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/bit-manipulation-java-bitwise-bit-shift-operations/#:~:text=Java%20uses%20another%20approach%2C%20which%20is%20called%20two%27s,by%20given%20number%20of%20positions%20to%20the%20right](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/bit-manipulation-java-bitwise-bit-shift-operations/#:%7E:text=Java%20uses%20another%20approach%2C%20which%20is%20called%20two%27s,by%20given%20number%20of%20positions%20to%20the%20right).

Comment: Highly appreciated !!. I get the point now.